# Xamarin.FormsMaps dont exist in namespace

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this namespaces:

```
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
```

I'm tring to put `Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` in `protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.
But i'm getting: `Cannot resolve symbol 'FormsMaps'`
I have this nuget packages: 
Xamarine.Forms 5.0.0.2012
Xamarine.Forms.Maps 5.0.0.2612
Xamarine.GooglePlayServices.Maps

Comment: you need to include the `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` namespace

Comment: @Jason still not working.

Answer (score 0):

[The official document about the Maps in the xamarin forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup#map-initialization) said:

> The Map control is provided by the Xamarin.Forms.Maps NuGet package,
> which should be added to every project in the solution.

Please make sure that you have installed the **Xamarin.Forms.Maps NuGet package** in the project's android part.